# Converting XAML to code for dynamic control

Tags: silverlight, xaml

The designer created some XAML VisualState code that works fine when built as XAML.  It is now my task to convert this XAML into Code Behind that is a custom Template control inheriting from ChildWindow that will build animations to transition between various "windows" that are all child UserControls to this ChildWindow.

I have written all the code, however when I run the any of the Animations, I get an error that Silverlight "cannot resolve targetproperty '(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)' "

This is the origional XAML

```
<VisualState x:Name="AtRegistration">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="WindowContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Content).Children[0].(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Collapsed" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="WindowContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Content).Children[1].(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Visible" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="AtLogin">
    <Storyboard>
        ... XAML omitted ...
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualTransition From="AtRegistration" To="AtLogin">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)">
                ... XAML OMITTED ...
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            ... XAML OMITTED ...
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualTransition>
    <VisualTransition From="AtLogin" To="AtRegistration">
        ... XAML OMITTED ...
    </VisualTransition>
</VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
```

... XAML OMITTED ...

The above XAML works fine, however when I write the code, this does not.  I'm assuming its something I am doing wrong in code, but I cannot find it.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
base.OnApplyTemplate();

var content = (ContentPresenter)GetTemplateChild( "WindowContentPresenter" );
m_contentRoot = (Grid)GetTemplateChild( "ContentRoot" );

var grid = (Grid)GetTemplateChild( "Root" );

if( grid != null )
{
    // Create the state group
    var animGroup = new VisualStateGroup();
    animGroup.SetValue( NameProperty, "AnimationStates" );

    var grp = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups( grid );
    grp.Add( animGroup );

    for( int i = 0; i < MultiControls.Count; i++ )
    {
        var state = new VisualState();
        state.SetValue( NameProperty, GetControlName( i ) );
        animGroup.States.Add( state );

        state.Storyboard = new Storyboard();

        // create an animation for each of the multi controls
        for( int j = 0; j < MultiControls.Count; j ++ )
        {
            // Create the storyboard
            var anim = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            Storyboard.SetTarget( state.Storyboard, content );
            anim.SetValue( Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath( string.Format( "(Content).Children[{0}].(UIElement.Visibility)", j ) ) );
            anim.KeyFrames.Add( new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    {
                                        KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan( new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0 ) ),
                                        Value = j == i ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed
                                    } );

            state.Storyboard.Children.Add( anim );

            // Don't create a transition to and from the other states.
            if( i == j )
                continue;

            // Create the Transition
            var trans = new VisualTransition { From = GetControlName( j ), To = GetControlName( i ) };
            animGroup.Transitions.Add( trans );
            trans.Storyboard = new Storyboard();

            var dbl = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames { BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 0 ) };
            Storyboard.SetTarget( trans.Storyboard, m_contentRoot );
            dbl.SetValue( Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath( "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" ) );
            trans.Storyboard.Children.Add( dbl );

            ... CODE OMITTED ...
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my Template XAML I have this:

```
<Grid x:Name="Overlay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" Background="{TemplateBinding OverlayBrush}" Opacity="{TemplateBinding OverlayOpacity}"/>
<Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
<Grid.Projection>
    <PlaneProjection/>
</Grid.Projection>
```

Do you guys/gals have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the var dbl to the storyboard children and then setting it's value?

Comment: I tried: var dbl = new DoubleAnim.....(); trans.Storyboard.Children.Add( dbl ); And then set all of it's properties and that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Try changing the PropertyPath string to read "UIElement.Projection.(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" - notice the removal of the first parentheses. Basically, you need to play with that path because defining this path within source and xaml will differ.

Comment: I tried a bunch of variations and still wasn't able to get it to work.  I even tried to Google differences between PropertyPath in XAML and code behind, but that didn't return much. I then tried loading the entire working VisualState XAML using XamlReader.Load, but that was having issues resolving "WindowContentPresenter" even tho it clearly exists. I wonder if it has to do w/ the fact that it cannot resolve it when its first Parsed/Loaded ?

Comment: Have you tried changing it to "UIElement.Projection.RotationY"?

Comment: I tried it just now, and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of Storyboard.SetTarget should be the projection and not the m_contentroot. Then all you need to specify in the path is "RotationY".